# How do i update CoreData after a row movement in a UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm displaying a bunch of data in a UITableView, the source of my data is from an NSSet from a Core-Data many-to-many relationship. If a user moves a row inside the table view i want it to have a permanent affect inside Core-Data. So that when the table view is reloaded you can see the changes, and the NSSet is re-ordered the way the user left it after moving around the rows. I'm wondering what approach would be best for this. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614987-moverow you can use this, but be aware that you need a block AND inside the block you need to write into CoreData (otherwise you get a data inconsistency error)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this would work visually but wouldn't be persistent.

Comment: you need to persist inside the block

Comment: Is the CoreData relationship defined as ordered?

Comment: No, would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the relationship as ordered, it will be represented as `NSOrderedSet` instead of `NSSet`.  As its name implies, an ordered set allows you to indicate the order of the items it contains.  The best route to manipulating this to reflect your user's chosen sequence is the method [mutableOrderedSetValue(forKey:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1415479-mutableorderedsetvalueforkey) which will given you a mutable ordered set ([NSMutableOrderedSet](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableorderedset)) that you can re-order using various add, insert, move, replace, remove methods.

Comment: Ahh that would make sense yeah. I wasn't aware you could set a relationship as an ordered set. Thank you for the reply, i will give it a try and get back to you.